# (MVVM) Cannot use instance member 'model' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, uikit

1. I want access to SampleMoel's 'head' at ViewModel
2. How to fix this error?
3. this is MVVM(not Use combine, RxSwift ... only use Uikit)

`SampleViewModel.swift`

```
class SampleViewModel {
     
  var model: SampleModel?
  let changeData = Observer(model?.head) //Line error
   
  init() {
    self.model = SampleModel()
     
  }
  
  func changeLabel(_ tf: String) {
     
    self.changeData.value = tf
  }
   
}
```

`SampleModel.swift`

```
struct SampleModel {
   
   var head = "initValue"
  
}
```

Comment: Use an anonymous closure `let changeData:Observer = { return Observer(self.model?.head)  }()`

Comment: or assign in init.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your implementation as follows:

```
class SampleViewModel {
     
  private let model: SampleModel
  let changeData: Observer<String>
   
  init(model: SampleModel) {
    self.model = model
    changeData = Observer(model.head)
  }
  
  func changeLabel(_ tf: String) {
     
    self.changeData.value = tf
  }
   

}
```